# How can i solve this Lagrange Polynomial problem?

Tags: numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

It's probably one of the easiest Lagrange Polynomial problem but I don't know much about this topic. So here is the question.

Consider the graph of function $f(x)=\sin(⁡x)$ over interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Use two points $(0,0)$ and $(\frac{\pi}{2}, 1)$ to construct a Lagrange linear interpolation polynomial $P_1(x)$. Use this polynomial to approximate $\sin⁡(\frac{2\pi}{9})$ and ﬁnd the upper bound for the error in this approximation.

Comment: $P_1$ is a straight line going through the two given points. You _could_ use the general Lagrange formula for this, but you shouldn't, because it's unnecessarily complicated. Just find the formula for the straight line any way you feel comfortable, and you're good to go.

Comment: But i must solve this problem with Langrange formula. I can't create the data table to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can apply the liner interpolation, but using the Lagrange's formula you must see the definition.

Considering the points $\{(x_0,y_0), \dots, (x_N, y_N)\}$ you can define the [interpolation polynomial in the Lagrange form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) as:
$$
p_N(x) = \sum_{k=0}^N y_kL_k(x)
$$
where the Lagrange polynomial are:
$$
L_k(x) = \prod_{j=0, j \neq k}^N \frac{x-x_j}{x_k-x_j}
$$

In your case $N=1$ and

$$
L_0(x) = \frac{x -x_1}{x_1-x_0} = \frac{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}{ 0 - \frac{\pi}{2}} 
= \frac{\pi - 2x}{\pi}
$$
$$
L_1(x) = \frac{x - x_0}{x_1 - x_0} = \frac{x - 0}{\frac{\pi}{2} - 0} = \frac{2x}{\pi}
$$

Note that, according with the theory $L_k(x_j) = \delta_{kj}$, $L_0(x_0) = 1 \; L_0(x_1) = 0$ same for $L_1(x)$.
With these polynomials you obtain,
$$
p_1(x) = y_0L_0(x) + y_1L_1(x) = 0 + 1 \cdot \frac{2x}{\pi} = \frac{2x}{\pi}
$$

This imply that the 
$$
f(\frac{2\pi}{9}) = \sin(\frac{2\pi}{9}) \approx 0.64278760968653925
$$
$$
p_1(\frac{2\pi}{9}) = \frac{2}{\pi} \cdot \frac{2\pi}{9} = \frac{4}{9} = 0.\bar{4}
$$
[image]

Now always from [the theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) you know that the error $E_N$ can be express as:

$$
E_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\zeta_x)}{(n+1)!} \omega_n(x) \quad 
\omega_N(x) = \prod_{k=0}^n (x - x_k)
$$

in your case
$$
E_1(x) = \frac{f^{(2)}(\zeta_x)}{(2)!}(x-x_0)(x-x_1) = 
\frac{f^{(2)}(\zeta_x)}{(2)!} \cdot x(x-\frac{\pi}{2})
$$

Now note that:

- $f(x) \, , x(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$ are [analytic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function), so they are continuous, and also their derivate.
- $f(x) \,, f^{(2)}(x)$ are bounded function, $|f^{(2)}(x)| \leq 1$
- you are workin on $\Omega = [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ it is compact and for [Weierstrass's theoreme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) continuous functions have max and min

for the above reason you can estimate the error as:
$$
|E_1(x)| \leq \frac{C_1C_2}{2!} \quad 
C_1 = \max_{\zeta \in \Omega} |f^{(2)}(\zeta)|  \quad
C_2 = \max_{\zeta \in \Omega} |\zeta(\zeta-\frac{\pi}{2})| \quad
$$

you can assume $C_1 \leq 1$ and $C_2 \leq \frac{\pi^2}{16}$.
This comes from a simple study of function, critical point in $\frac{\pi}{4}$, it is a max for $|\zeta(\zeta-\frac{\pi}{2})|$  so

$$
|E_1(x)| \leq 1 \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{16} \cdot \frac{1}{2!} = \frac{\pi^2}{32} \approx 0.30842513753404244
$$

Note that the case of $\frac{2\pi}{9}$ is according with this estimate.

Comment: Thank you so much, i get it clearly :) You my friend a lifesaver.